# Staging Multiple Git Branches on a single server

Tags: git, deployment

Is it a bad idea to use a single staging server for staging multiple git branches?

For example, if the continuous integration server automatically runs an Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc. provisioning suite after all tests are completed and deploys the application to StagingApplicationServer.com/< branch name here >

This would allow master, develop, and other feature branches to be stage-able.

If this isn't a bad idea, is there a way of being able to separate the different branches staged on a single system? So, for example, the Nginx/Redis/MongoDB service for branch 1 can be different than branch 2 and be torn-down easily.

Spinning up Amazon EC2 instances for a brief period of time would be ideal, but it's unfortunately not an option. Also, using subdomains is not an option for this particular application.

**EDIT:**

For specific details, the application is a Python Flask application using Redis, MongoDB. Servers are provisioned with Ansible.

**EDIT2:**

To clarify, I'm concerned about it being a bad idea because everywhere you read that your development, staging, and production environments should be as close as each other as possible. This means that if your deployment strategy works for staging, you should be able to replicate it without issue for the production environment. i.e. if your Ansible playbooks work on staging, they'll work for production.

In order to accommodate the multiple branches at staging you'll need to customize the Nginx, for example, configuration. You may also need to change how your databases are configure, or you may run extra steps to provision a VM to contain your databases, etc. All of these things end up making your staging environment different from your production one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason this would be a bad idea. Staging implies a non-production service, so you can have all your staging happen on one server without concern for redundancy, performance, etc. One other reason for separating applications and instances of applications is for security, but once again for a non-production service this is less of a concern, unless you host a copy of your production data on your staging server (which is another type of separation to think about). If there are security concerns, and you can't use subdomains, you could still use proxying in nginx to divide the instances up across multiple VMs. But, in the simplest form, you'd just run them all on the same instance, and use 'location' directives to determine what app each path runs.

nginx doesn't care how you divide up your applications, though you'll need to configure a different proxy configuration (either different ports or different locations for configuration files, depending on the app server) to each application server based on the directory. How you do this will depend somewhat on what your app server is, which you have not specified.

For example, with Ruby using the Passenger application server, you would follow these instructions: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Notice that Passenger hides some of the implementation details from you, so you don't need to think about ports, only directories. Whereas in the following example, you'd specify the port for proxying and it would need to be different for each application instance.

With Perl Mojolicious, you could follow this example: http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-5.27/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook.pod#Nginx

Note that the `location` section in either example can be replicated for as many paths as you need independent instances of your app. It's the same as running multiple apps; you just give each one its own directory and configuration files.

I suspect the reason you haven't gotten any answers thus far is that you haven't provided any concrete information about your deployment. I'm finding it hard to offer advice when you've specified you'll be using "Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc." and "Redis/MongoDB"...are you using all of these things, despite the fact that they do very similar jobs? Most people choose one deployment tool (from Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc.) and one key/value store (Redis/MongoDB). Configuration examples for all of these, and the caveats for things to look out for will be different for each.

Anyway, the short answer to your question is: Yes, you can do that, and there's no technical reason you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply swelljoe! I have never heard about Passenger before, which certainly seems easier to configure/manage than gunicorn. I updated my original question with details on my specific deployment, as well as clarified why I thought it originally was a bad idea, i.e. the configuration between staging and production would be different. Are my original concerns founded, or is it not too big of a deal considering the Ansible playbooks should be thoroughly tested too?

Comment: I don't know that I would consider that a big enough difference to impede testing and deployment, though some folks might. Given your limitations (no subdomains, sounds like you can't spin up new VMs for each staging environment), I don't know how else you can do it. If the alternative is not staging and testing at all...that's obviously not preferable. You can use includes in the nginx config to isolate the differences between environments, so those differences are testable and verifiable independently of other configuration variables.

Comment: Oh, and you could also use completely separate instances of nginx, on different ports, if you wanted to isolate further.